# Unable to run the front end of an application developed using reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, angular, express, npm

I opened an existing project through visual studio code. Front end of that following system has been developed using "React". Now i have problem in how to run that and see its interfaces.
(I dont use any html files)

I did these two command in command prompt:
npm install
npm start

after npm start command instead of running the app in the browser, i got some errors.
the below error occurred.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.5
3 info using node@v14.5.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle front-end@0.1.0~prestart: front-end@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle front-end@0.1.0~start: front-end@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle front-end@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle front-end@0.1.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;F:\Upulka\SLIIT_Campus\Year_2\2nd_Semester\ITP_Project\WijesingheJewellers_system\RW-Jewellery-Automated-System-React-SpringBoot\itp-project\front-end\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;;C:\Users\NAYOMI\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\NAYOMI\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle front-end@0.1.0~start: CWD: F:\Upulka\SLIIT_Campus\Year_2\2nd_Semester\ITP_Project\WijesingheJewellers_system\RW-Jewellery-Automated-System-React-SpringBoot\itp-project\front-end
10 silly lifecycle front-end@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle front-end@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle front-end@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: front-end@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:314:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1051:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5)
14 verbose pkgid front-end@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd F:\Upulka\SLIIT_Campus\Year_2\2nd_Semester\ITP_Project\WijesingheJewellers_system\RW-Jewellery-Automated-System-React-SpringBoot\itp-project\front-end
16 verbose Windows_NT 6.3.9600
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"

18 verbose node v14.5.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.5
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error front-end@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the front-end@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to run `npm install` first.

And then after it is successfully installed, try again with `npm run start`